# Visual Studio Cordova IOS remote build fail

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am using visual studio to develop cordova apps, I have followed this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx to configure remote ios build on my MAC virtual machine.

I added the remote configuration on my VS and it is pairing successfully but when trying to run my app the VS buils always fail and say that no a remote iOS build agent has not been configured. Configure one in Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Remote Agent Configuration,

Here is my remote build configured in VS [image]

And here is the build error

[image]

And here is my remotebuild server running

[image]

Any one could help in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did the remote configuration for my cordova app not in the "Options->Cross Platform->C++->iOS" section, but in "Options-Tools for Apache Cordova->Remote Agent Configuration" and it worked like a charm. Do you developing C++ Plugins or why did you configure that part?

Comment: In Visual Studio : TOOLS -> Tools for apache cordova -> Clear Cordova Cache. If it does not work try to run the osx compiler without encription --secure=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Bjoerg, Your solution works.

I did the remote configuration for my cordova app not in the "Options->Cross Platform->C++->iOS" section, but in "Options-Tools for Apache Cordova->Remote Agent Configuration" and it worked like a charm

Regards